# Why is Bernoulli equation applicable here eventhough we can see that streamlines would be like curve not straight? Also at orifice speed is not steady

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, flow, bernoulli-equation

Consider the famous setup of Toricelli ones where a cylindrical container of large area $A$ and a very small hole of area $A'$ is there at the bottom (in the curve side of the container ), now due to mass conservation its natural to say A$v_{top}$ = A'$v_{orifice}$, we can see $v_{orifice}$ is changing with time (so its velocity is not steady *) , one more thing is (to check whether its irrotational or rotational) we can imagine dropping a toothpick on the top and seeing its motion as its goes with the flow of water , we can see it will rotate a bit during whole motion until comes out of the orifice ( so its rotational flow **) so why is then bernoulli equation applicable here as such for that to be working it needs flow to be steady and irrotational which is not the situation here isn't?[ Assume fluid is non-viscous as always assumed in toricelli type problems ]

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli's equation assumes conservation of energy. That can change with time if the change is system wide. The equation becomes less accurate if there is fiction or turbulence.

Comment: Well, if there is fiction in the equation all bets are off! (Joys of autocorrect???)

Comment: I mean Sir isnt the flow rotational type here as we can see from the streamlines too isnt ? So why is bernoulli applicable?